# Separable polynomial in field and its extension

Tags: field-theory

[image]

The first paragraph of above excerpt from Lang's book I have understood easily.

But I cannot understand one moment from the second one: if $f$ is separable polynomial in $k[X]$ with $f(\alpha)=0$, the we can consider $f$ as polynomial from $F[X]$. But in order to conlude that $\alpha$ is separable over $F$ (here we are using the first paragraph) we need to show that $f$ is separable over $F$.

If $k\subset F$ and $f$ is separable over $k$ how to show that $f$ is separable over $F$?

I have tried some approaches but did not get smth good.

Would be grateful for help!

Comment: A polynomial $f$ is separable (over whatever field it lies in) if and only if $\gcd\left(f, f'\right) = 1$. But the gcd does not depend on the base field (it is computed by the Euclidean algorithm *for polynomials*, which is insensitive to the base field); so separability of $f$ does not depend on the base field either.

Comment: @darijgrinberg, Thanks for answer! Good and useful answer! +1. I'll try to clarify my question: if $k\subset K$ and $f\in k[X]$, $f$ is separable over $k$ (i.e. $f$ has no multiple roots in $k^a$), then $f$ is separable over $K$ (i.e. $f$ has no multiple roots on $K^a$). That's what I was asking. How to prove this fact directly?

Comment: You mean without the equivalent definition via gcd? That I'm not sure about (not used to working with algebraic closures -- it's much easier to avoid them).

Comment: @darijgrinberg, If $f$ is separable over $k$ then $\text{gcd}(f,f')=1$. Since as you said GCD does not depend on ground field then $f$ is also separable over $K$. Is my reasoning correct? Yes I know this fact (=relation of gcd with multiple roots) but thank you that you've showed how to apply it in my question!

Comment: Yes, that's the exact argument I meant.